# PHP case-insensitive in_array function

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to do case-insensitive comparison when using the `in_array` function?

So with a source array like this:

```
$a= array(
 'one',
 'two',
 'three',
 'four'
);
```

The following lookups would all return true:

```
in_array('one', $a);
in_array('two', $a);
in_array('ONE', $a);
in_array('fOUr', $a);
```

What function or set of functions would do the same? I don't think `in_array` itself can do this.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

you can use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep):

```
$a= array(
 'one',
 'two',
 'three',
 'four'
);

print_r( preg_grep( "/ONe/i" , $a ) );
```

Comment: using regular expressions isn't a good solution, because it can be slow... maybe array_map is faster

Comment: To make it a drop-in replacement for in_array, returning a bool, it becomes:  `count(preg_grep('/^'.preg_quote($needle).'/$',$a)>0)`. Not so elegant, then. (Notice the ^ and $ characters are required, unless partial matching is desired.) However if you actually want the matching entries returned, I like this solution.

Comment: The last comment contains a syntax error: /$ should be $/ instead.

Comment: @DarrenCook as far as i know a bool cast would also work (bool)preg_grep('/^'.preg_quote($needle).'$/',$a), as an empty array would cast to false

Comment: @arraintxo You're right, and (after some thought) I think I prefer that.

Comment: @arraintxo forgot the ignore_case part: `(bool)preg_grep('/^'.preg_quote($needle).'$/i',$a), $haystack)`

Comment: Seems like the easier way to go is to just convert to lowercase.

Comment: Since preg_grep returns an array of matches, we should check that it is not empty to see if there is a match:  `if( !empty( preg_grep('/^'.preg_quote($needle).'$/i', $haystackArray) )){ /*do stuff */ }`

Comment: Warning: this will not work if you have non standard characters like "Ł"  preg_grep( "/ł/i"['Ł'] ) equals false

Answer (score 290):

The obvious thing to do is just convert the search term to lowercase:

```
if (in_array(strtolower($word), $array)) { 
  ...
```

of course if there are uppercase letters in the array you'll need to do this first:

```
$search_array = array_map('strtolower', $array);
```

and search that. There's no point in doing `strtolower` on the whole array with every search.

Searching arrays however is linear. If you have a large array or you're going to do this a lot, it would be better to put the search terms in key of the array as this will be *much* faster access:

```
$search_array = array_combine(array_map('strtolower', $a), $a);
```

then

```
if ($search_array[strtolower($word)]) { 
  ...
```

The only issue here is that array keys must be unique so if you have a collision (eg "One" and "one") you will lose all but one.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Adding regular expressions sometimes just makes 2 problems.

Comment: Wouldn't array_flip here be an even faster solution, instead of array_combine?

$search_array = array_flip(array_map('strtolower', $a));

Comment: one line: in_array(strtolower($word), array_map('strtolower', $array))

Comment: @Akira Yamamoto - what's with the ["fix syntax" edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2166522/2)? We're not allowed to fix code here. I rolled it back.

Comment: Or use array_change_key_case() https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php

Answer (score 139):

```
function in_arrayi($needle, $haystack) {
    return in_array(strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack));
}
```

From [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: You should blockquote code (or anything really) you get from somewhere else.

Comment: Just to be clear. It's not a criticism. Just a suggestion (and only my opinion, nothing official). :) At least if I copy a code snippet from a page I'll block quote it.

Comment: Plus, using a code block better describes it, as it is 'code'. Block quoting it does not allow for it to be properly formatted.

Comment: I stand corrected, after using the actual button to add `>` to every line, it works. I am just used to manually putting the `>` at the first line.

Comment: I'm used to using ctrl-Q to do it. That has one problem with code blocks because for some reason it wraps lines. Don't ask me why. But you can just either correct that or manually put a `>` at the start of each line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the formating. I still don't copy answers. :)

Comment: No you didn't. But that's the issue with not blockquoting. Otherwise it would be clearer (on both of your parts). It did look a little weird though that you'd both put the same code snippet and both put the same text in the same position with you putting link text being the only difference. Anyway +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 57):

```
function in_arrayi($needle, $haystack) {
    return in_array(strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack));
}
```

Source: [php.net in_array manual page.](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#89256)

Comment: If you know what is in the array, you can leave out the array_map; but this is a good example.

Comment: I did actually. Because mapping the array on every call is, well, ludicrous.

Comment: Also, assuming (like Chacha) this comes direct from the docs, it's better to block quote it.

Answer (score 11):

Say you want to use the in_array, here is how you can make the search case insensitive.

Case insensitive in_array():

```
foreach($searchKey as $key => $subkey) {

     if (in_array(strtolower($subkey), array_map("strtolower", $subarray)))
     {
        echo "found";
     }

}
```

Normal case sensitive:

```
foreach($searchKey as $key => $subkey) {

if (in_array("$subkey", $subarray))

     {
        echo "found";
     }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The above is correct if we assume that arrays can contain only strings, but arrays can contain other arrays as well. Also in_array() function can accept an array for $needle, so strtolower($needle) is not going to work if $needle is an array and array_map('strtolower', $haystack) is not going to work if $haystack contains other arrays, but will result in "PHP warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given".

Example:

```
$needle = array('p', 'H');
$haystack = array(array('p', 'H'), 'U');
```

So i created a helper class with the releveant methods, to make case-sensitive and case-insensitive in_array() checks. I am also using mb_strtolower() instead of strtolower(), so other encodings can be used. Here's the code:

```
class StringHelper {

public static function toLower($string, $encoding = 'UTF-8')
{
    return mb_strtolower($string, $encoding);
}

/**
 * Digs into all levels of an array and converts all string values to lowercase
 */
public static function arrayToLower($array)
{
    foreach ($array as &$value) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_string($value):
                $value = self::toLower($value);
                break;
            case is_array($value):
                $value = self::arrayToLower($value);
                break;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

/**
 * Works like the built-in PHP in_array() function — Checks if a value exists in an array, but
 * gives the option to choose how the comparison is done - case-sensitive or case-insensitive
 */
public static function inArray($needle, $haystack, $case = 'case-sensitive', $strict = false)
{
    switch ($case) {
        default:
        case 'case-sensitive':
        case 'cs':
            return in_array($needle, $haystack, $strict);
            break;
        case 'case-insensitive':
        case 'ci':
            if (is_array($needle)) {
                return in_array(self::arrayToLower($needle), self::arrayToLower($haystack), $strict);
            } else {
                return in_array(self::toLower($needle), self::arrayToLower($haystack), $strict);
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * in_array function variant that performs case-insensitive comparison when needle is a string.
 *
 * @param mixed $needle
 * @param array $haystack
 * @param bool $strict
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function in_arrayi($needle, array $haystack, bool $strict = false): bool
{

    if (is_string($needle)) {

        $needle = strtolower($needle);

        foreach ($haystack as $value) {

            if (is_string($value)) {
                if (strtolower($value) === $needle) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;

    }

    return in_array($needle, $haystack, $strict);

}


/**
 * in_array function variant that performs case-insensitive comparison when needle is a string.
 * Multibyte version.
 *
 * @param mixed $needle
 * @param array $haystack
 * @param bool $strict
 * @param string|null $encoding
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function mb_in_arrayi($needle, array $haystack, bool $strict = false, ?string $encoding = null): bool
{

    if (null === $encoding) {
        $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
    }

    if (is_string($needle)) {

        $needle = mb_strtolower($needle, $encoding);

        foreach ($haystack as $value) {

            if (is_string($value)) {
                if (mb_strtolower($value, $encoding) === $needle) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;

    }

    return in_array($needle, $haystack, $strict);

}
```

Comment: Finally.  It took 8 years before someone stepped up and provided the most efficient technique -- **an early `return`**. When only needing to find 1 of the needle, it is pointless to keep iterating after finding it.  I would fix a typo, bake in the $strict concept and make some refinements though, perhaps something close to https://3v4l.org/WCTi2 .  This post isn't perfect, but its heart is in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple function to check for a insensitive value in an array the code is below.

**function:**

```
function in_array_insensitive($needle, $haystack) {
   $needle = strtolower($needle);
   foreach($haystack as $k => $v) {
      $haystack[$k] = strtolower($v);
   }
   return in_array($needle, $haystack);
}
```

**how to use:**

```
$array = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
var_dump(in_array_insensitive('fOUr', $array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is 14 years old - I have an answer that's an actual answer and not a new ramshackle function.

The problem is that the in_array function is case sensitive - and there isn't any way to change that - so don't try. You could upper or lowercase everything - but where's the fun in that? There are a ton of other PHP array functions we can choose from, surely we can do the same thing if given the right function and parameters.

That function is...

[array_uintersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) - computes the intersection of arrays, compares data by callback.

The first trick is to give an array as the needle, which is easy enough - by simply surrounding the search string with square braces. Next, we pass the comparison array - self-explanatory.  Finally, the third parameter is the callback function, in this case "[strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)" (case-insensitive string comparison).  To make it behave like in_array - we cast the result as a bool.

```
$needle = "abc";
$haystack = ["Abc","deF","gHi"];
$result = (bool)array_uintersect([$needle],$haystack,"strcasecmp");
```

In this case, $result = true;

A clever person might realize that if you don't cast as a bool, the haystack is placed first, and the needle array second - your result will contain the cased match from the haystack instead of the lowercased needle.

```
$result = array_uintersect($haystack,[$needle],"strcasecmp");
print_r($result);
Array
(
    [0] => "Abc"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = [1 => 'funny', 3 => 'meshgaat', 15 => 'obi', 2 => 'OMER'];  

$b = 'omer';

function checkArr($x,$array)
{
    $arr = array_values($array);
    $arrlength = count($arr);
    $z = strtolower($x);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $arrlength; $i++) {
        if ($z == strtolower($arr[$i])) {
            echo "yes";
        }  
    } 
};

checkArr($b, $a);
```

Comment: Please, add a descriptioin of the solution you are proposing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_agent = 'yandeX';
$bots = ['Google','Yahoo','Yandex'];        
        
foreach($bots as $b){
     if( stripos( $user_agent, $b ) !== false ) return $b;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regex case insensitive search - this will ignore the case in both the haystack and the needle:

```
$haystack = array('MacKnight', 'MacManus', 'MacManUS', 'MacMurray');
$needle='MacMANUS';
$regex='/'.$needle.'/i';
$matches  = preg_grep ($regex, $haystack);
if($m=current($matches)){ // find first case insensitive match
   echo 'match found: '.$m;
}else{
   echo 'no match found.';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

- `in_array` accepts these parameters : `in_array(search,array,type)`
- if the search parameter is a string and the type parameter is set to TRUE, the search is case-sensitive.
- so in order to make the search ignore the case, it would be enough to use it like this :

```php
$a = array( 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' );
$b = in_array( 'ONE', $a, false );
```

Comment: The third parameter controls whether or not the _type_ of the variable is checked, not the _case_. When `true` strict type comparisons will be used, e.g. `'1' !== 1`. When `false` type juggling will be used, e.g. `'1' == 1`. See http://php.net/in_array and http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php for documentation.