# PHP case-insensitive array search functions

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP case-insensitive in_array function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166512/php-case-insensitive-in-array-function)

Is it possible to do case-insensitive comparison when using the `in_array` function?

So with a source array like this:

```
$a= array(
 'one',
 'two',
 'three',
 'four'
);
```

The following lookups would all return true:

```
in_array('one', $a);
in_array('ONE', $a);
in_array('fOUr', $a);
```

What function or set of functions would do the same? I don't think `in_array` itself can do this. Because it is case sensitive.

Comment: do you assume the array is all lowercase or can the array contain values in any case?

Comment: no The can contain any case values.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to apply strtolower on each element of the array, use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

`in_array(strtolower('ONE'), array_map('strtolower', $a));`

Comment: Edited to works with any of this strings. @Manikandan: you not really need arary_map here if $a always consist of lowercased strings