# Whitelist function help needed - in_array is not case sensitive for some reason

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP case-insensitive in_array function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166512/php-case-insensitive-in-array-function)

I'm making a function to validate input by having an `$input` variable and a `$whitelist` variable. Both are strings and the function parses the `$whitelist` variable and makes it into a character array to use on the string.

For some reason the `in_array` function is not distinguishing a lowercase letter from an uppercase one (at least I think that's what's happening).

Link to code: http://pastebin.com/eadAV7gg

Answer (score 0):

Why not match against the lowercase value of the letter. If you match it in the if statement, then you don't have to worry about changing the actual `$input` string:

```
foreach ($inputArray as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($whitelistArray as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        if (in_array(strtolower($value), $whitelistArray))
        {
            //Do nothing, check passed
        }
        else
        {
            unset($inputArray[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

A much shorter version of what you have could be accomplished with:

```
$input = "ATTT";
$whitelist = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$output = '';

for($x=0; $x<strlen($input);$x++){
    if(stristr($whitelist,substr(strtolower($input),$x,1))){
        $output .= substr($input,$x,1);
    }
}
echo $output;
```

Or to implement as a function:

```
function whitelist_string($input=''){

    $whitelist = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $output = '';

    for($x=0; $x<strlen($input);$x++){
        if(stristr($whitelist,substr(strtolower($input),$x,1))){
            $output .= substr($input,$x,1);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

echo whitelist_string('ATTT').'<br>';
echo whitelist_string('Hello88 World!').'<br>';
```

Comment: No that's the issue, I DON'T want it to be case insensitive, A shouldn't equal a - your script has the same issue for me

Comment: then why not add A-Z (caps) to the whitelist?

Comment: I only want to replace lowercase a-z, it is for some reason removing the uppercase when all I want to replace is lower. So my whitelist is "abcd...z" and it's removing capital letters too