# PHP If statement disallowing certain words from an array

Tags: php, arrays, post, if-statement

Just after some help, I have an array with disallowed words in which I cant show here as they are obscene.

What I want to do is check `if $_POST['urlprefix'] !=` one of the array elements, I am wondering what the easiest way to do this is. Obviously the below only stops one element of the array.

Thanks for any help you may provide

```
if($_POST['urlprefix'] != $arr[1]) {
  print("You've Passed");
} else {
  print("You Are Not Allowed To Use That URL Prefix");
}
```

Comment: Check out [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array).

Answer (score 1):

The examples with `in_array()` are a quick way to achieve that. You can also use a [case-insensitive in_array function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166512/php-case-insensitive-in-array-function) by using `preg_grep`.

But, if *ship* is a bad word, do you want to allow **ship***py* ? The following code will forbid any prefixes that *contain* the word, too.

```
$disallow = false;
foreach($arr as $bad_word) {
    if(stripos($_POST['urlprefix'], $bad_word) !== false) {
         $disallow = true;
         break;
    }
}

if($disallow) {
    die('Bad words in URL!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in_array function :

```
if (!in_array($_POST['urlprefix'], $arr))
{
    print("You've Passed");
}
else
{
    print("You Are Not Allowed To Use That URL Prefix");
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that even existed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way. `in_array` is **slower** than this method. See more about [**array_flip**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php).

```
$words = array('damn','shit');
$flip = array_flip($words);
if(!isset($flip[$_POST['urlprefix']])){
    //valid url
}
```

Comment: You can't do `array_flip($words))[$_POST['urlprefix']]` in PHP versions less than 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function. It checks if a value exists in an array

```
if(!in_array($_POST['urlprefix'], $arr)) {
      print("You've Passed");
    } else {
      print("You Are Not Allowed To Use That URL Prefix");
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid only-code answers, explain a bit your code. For example, here you can tell that he's looking for in_array function, and put a link to the documentation.

Comment: Ok sorry, i will do that