# PHP: How do I change a variable dependent on another variable? (Newbie stuff)

Tags: php, if-statement, variables

I'm pretty new to webcoding and would like to improve a bit in php, but I'm already stuck :/

What I am trying to do is to have a sentence like
"**Simon likes apples**" 
Now I have an input form for the name so I can choose the name. So it looks like 
"***$name* likes apples**"

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="name1" name="name1"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Apply"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
    <?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        $name1 = $_REQUEST['name1'];
        echo "$name1 likes apples.";
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Everything fine till now. Whatever name I type in replaces $name. Now what I want to do is to change the "likes" to "like" whenever i type in a pronoun (I, You, They etc.), which makes sense obviously. Now here is where I don't know what to do. My current code (which doesnt work) looks like this:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        $name1 = $_REQUEST['name1'];
          if ($name1 = "I", "You") {
          $verb = "like";
          }
          else {
          $verb = "likes";
          }
        echo "$name1 $verb apples";
        }
    ?>
```

Also is there a way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Try `in_array`.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166512/php-case-insensitive-in-array-function (scroll down to the second answer.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473542/case-insensitive-string-comparison about doing the comparison case-insensitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are few problems in your code .

single `=` means SET my variable to whatever string is after . so if you want to see if your variable is equal to a string like `You` , you have to use `==` , it will return true or false .

now we want to say if my variable was `You` or `I` , change my second variable to like . thats gonna be the output :

```
  if ($name1 == "I" || $name1 == "You") {
  $verb = "like";
  }
  else {
  $verb = "likes";
  }
```

so now it says if `$name1` was equal to I OR(`||`) `$name1` was equal to `You` , change the `$verb` to like .

we use `||` as OR and `&&` as AND.

if you want echo variables and string you should use `.` as split between your variable and string . so it will be like this :

```
echo $name1 . $verb . "apples";
```

it's kind of like `+` but not in a math way , it just means add .

**UPDATE**

yes . there is a way to check your string case insensitive . you have to use [strcasecmp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) .

in your code , it should be like :

```
  if (strcasecmp($name1,"I") == 0 || strcasecmp($name1,"You") == 0 ) {
  $verb = "like";
  }
  else {
  $verb = "likes";
  }
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question about how to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Case insensitive replacement, `$lut` table defines what should be replaced with what. You may place it inside the `replaceMe` function if you don't want to change it over time.

Code:

```
<?php

$lut = [
    'like' => [
        'I',
        'You',
        'They',
        'We',
    ],
    'likes' => [
        'she',
        'he',
        'it',
        'someone',
        'somebody',
    ],
];

function replaceMe(string $name, array $lut) : string
{
    foreach ($lut as $key => $value) {
        $nameLower = strtolower($name);
        $valueLowerArr = array_map(
            function($input) {
                return strtolower($input);
            },
            $value
        );
        if (in_array($nameLower, $valueLowerArr)) {
            return strtolower($key);
        }
    }
    return '';
}

$name = 'She';
echo "$name = " . replaceMe($name, $lut) . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

$name = 'I';
echo "$name = " . replaceMe($name, $lut) . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

$name = 'iT';
echo "$name = " . replaceMe($name, $lut) . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

$name = 'TheY';
echo "$name = " . replaceMe($name, $lut) . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

$name = 'nobody';
echo "$name = " . replaceMe($name, $lut) . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Gives Result:

```
She = likes<br>
I = like<br>
iT = likes<br>
TheY = like<br>
nobody = <br>
```