# Correct use of in_array()

Tags: php

This code:

```
if ( in_array($some_variable, ['uk','in'], true ) ) {
```

is same as:

```
if ( $some_variable == 'uk' && $some_variable == 'in' ) {
```

How I can do the first example using `in_array()` to be similar to:

```
if ( $some_variable == 'uk' OR $some_variable == 'in' ) {
```

`OR` not `&&`

Comment: Your second snippet should use || to have equivalent behavior.  A variable can’t be equal to two different strings

Comment: I'm guessing by the fact that you've answered your own question without realizing it, and you're new here, you're simply not getting the expected behavior. And I'm guessing by the misunderstanding of what the third parameter does, as well as the abbreviation content of your array, you thought that to be a case-insensitive flag, as offered by some other functions, instead of strict type-matching. So, forgive me if my assumptions are incorrect, but I suspect this is the actual answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166512/php-case-insensitive-in-array-function

Answer (score 3):

You did it already. `in_array($item, $array)` checks to see if the item exists in the set, so it essentially is an OR. If it were an AND, then it would always return false, unless the array contains nothing multiple instances of the same value. By the way, the third parameter `true` looks for a strict type-match, so it'd be like saying `$item === $element`, as opposed to the default value match of `$item == $element`. (i.e. `1 == true // true`, `1 === true // false`. Therefore, `in_array(1, [true, 'true', 2], true); // false`, `in_array(1, [true, 'true', 2]); // true (I think)`.)

Comment: Thank you! So, by removing `true` I guess that would be exactly what I'm looking for.